# The value of $\sin(\theta)$ from two triangles, one having sides $a,b,c$ and the other having the reciprocals

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$a,b,c$ are the sides of a right triangle whose smallest angle is $\theta$ and $\frac 1a,\frac 1b,\frac 1c$ are the sides of another right triangle then what is the value of $\sin\theta$.

I got two relations

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
 and 
$$c^2=\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2+b^2}$$
Which can be rewritten as

$(a^2+b^2)^2=a^2b^2$
or,
$a^4+b^4+a^2b^2=0$

Now if $b= c \cos\theta$ & $a=c \sin\theta$:

Then,

$c^4\sin^4\theta+c^4\cos^4\theta+c^4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=0$

$c^4{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}^2=2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$

$c^4\cdot 1= 2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$
 I am lost after this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $a\le b < c$.

Without affecting the conditions, we can scale $a,b,c$, so that $c=1$.

Then $a \le b < 1$, and $\sin(\theta)=a$.

Thus, our goal is to solve for $a$.

By the Pythagorean theorem, we get the equations
\begin{align*}
&
\!\!
\begin{cases}
{\displaystyle{a^2+b^2=1}}\\[4pt]
{\displaystyle{1+\frac{1}{b^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}}}\\
\end{cases}
\\[10pt]
\text{Then}\;\;&1+\frac{1}{b^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2b^2+a^2=b^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2(1-a^2)+a^2=1-a^2&&\text{[since $b^2=1-a^2$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2a^2-a^4=1-a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-2a^2+a^4=a^2-1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-2a^2+a^4=a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(1-a^2)^2=a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-a^2=\pm{a}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-a^2=a&&\text{[since $0 < a < 1$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}&&\text{[since $a > 0$]}\\[4pt]\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you ! But can you say a word or two more about the scaling of c ?

Comment: If we scale the original lengths $a,b,c$ by an arbitrary positive factor, $t$ say, the new lengths $ta,tb,tc$ satisfy the same conditions, and the angles remain the same. So we can choose $t=1/c$, and then just relabel the scaled sides as $a,b,1$ (or equivalently, just start with a similar version of the original triangle which has $c=1$).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a<b<c$. Now identify the legs and the hypotenuse of the second triangle! In the end you want the value of ${a\over c}$.